# obj-c: playing mp3 file in Document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to play a song from app's document directory, here is some code. 
The URL, Asset, PlayerItem and Player all seem to have valid values. Still the song doesn't play. Any thoughts why?

```
-(void) playFileAtLocalURL: (NSString*) urlAsString{
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:urlAsString])
{
    self.asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString ]];
    self.playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:self.asset];
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
    [self.player play];

}
}
```

I have these two frameworks in my project

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

Comment: Not every sound file is playable. (It's worse than that; some sound files are playable on one device but not on another.) If this is a highly compressed mp3, that might be the source of the trouble.

Comment: Also, Krunal Darji makes a very good point: you must use `fileURLWithPath:`, not `URLWithString:`, in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are trying to play song from local path then you should use NSURL fileURLWithPath , also you are not adding status notification observer on player . Refer below sample source code:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    AVPlayer *_player;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *mp3Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"kk" ofType:@"mp3"];//Your Document mp3 path
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:mp3Path
                                                     ] options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *_playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    _player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:_playerItem];
    [_player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

}
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{

    if (object == _player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"])
    {
        if (_player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed)
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Status Failed");
        else if (_player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay)
        {
            //Start playing song
            [_player play];
        }
        else if (_player.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown)
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Status Unknown");
    }

}
@end
```

Comment: The `fileURLWithPath:` did it. I have observer in my code, just didn't put it in the question here for sake of ease. Thank you and happy Holidays!

Comment: As per Apple documentation it will be better if you add observer & see what is your player status , because some mp3 can't be play due to error so it is better to check player is reedit play state or not & then start playing song.